# How do I access these knockout pseudo variables using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

[image]

Here's some of my code 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ph2DF.png)

Any and all help would be appreciated

Comment: Click the "enter image description here" to view the image. Sorry about that

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/RBI/comments/cqedp2/our_4_year_old_says_he_used_to_be_someone_named/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ko.dataFor` and `ko.contextFor` functions.  if you inspect the element then go to the console you can enter `ko.dataFor($0)` or `ko.contextFor($0)`  the $0 is the currently selected element in chromium based browsers.  this will give you some of the data you are looking for.  to unwrap all the observables in the viewmodel use `ko.toJS(ko.dataFor($0))`.

Comment: I keep getting either "ko is not defined" in the console or it's undefined in the javascript and $0 using ko.dataFor also gives me undefined or "$0 is not defined". I'm gonna edit this post and put some of the code

Comment: hmm that is strange. my understanding is that `ko` is a global variable added by knockout when it's loaded and you can see it defined in your image